# How to get image picker with jsonschema in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema

Can anyone please tell a simple solution to get image picker in UI form using json schema. code snippet would be wonderful.
It would be really helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am creating json schema for a form say Student..
which has id,dept,marks and a thumbnail image.
How do i define json schema so that when i form is rendered it has 3 text box for id, dept,marks and one image_picker in it.
i am trying something like this ..
  "title": "StudentDefinition",

    "type": "object",

    "properties": {

        "id": {

            "type": "string"

        },

         "ThunbnailImage": {

             "type": "image_picker",

         },